# Java Reflection: Invoke function in a inner static class

Tags: java, reflection

My simple `School` class looks like this:

```
public class School{
   ...
   public static class Student{
       public void register(){
          ...
       }
   }

}
```

As you see above, the `School` class has a inner public static class named `Student`. There is a method `register()` defined in `Student`.

In my main function, I am able to load the inner static `Student` class by:

```
Class<?> studentClass = Class.forName("School$Student");
```

I am wondering, with the above line of code, how could I invoke the `register()` function in java **reflection** way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a valid class, then you can access and invoke its methods with:

```
Method register = studentClass.getDeclaredMethod("register");
register.invoke(studentClass.newInstance());
```

Comment: But my Student class is a static class without an empty constructor. The "newInstance()" call will cause exception

Comment: @Mellon does it have any constructors?

Comment: @Mellon Every class has its default constructor (even nested/inner ones), unless you create separate one. Also default constructor will have same visibility as class so since `Student` is `public` class then you can have access to this constructor from anywhere.

Comment: @Mellon Based on example from your question `Student` doesn't have any constructors so you can use default one with `studentClass.newInstance()`. But in case it does have constructors you can select one of them with `studentClass.getConstructor(parameterTypes)` then just invoke its `newInstance` method with parameters you described in `getConstructor` like `studentClass.getConstructor(int.class, String.class).newInstance(1,"abc");`. This should solve your problem with lack of default constructor.